# Javascript to find whether device is present in a LAN

Tags: javascript, lan

How would you do that? The website [synology.com](http://find.synology.com) seems to be able to use JavaScript to peer into your LAN to see if one of its products is connected to your network.

Answer (score 3):

Pop open developer tools and it's super easy to figure out.  It sends requests to `diskstation.local`, `rackstation.local`, and `nvr.local`.

Their products broadcast local hostnames that anyone on the same LAN can see, and this website just looks for them.  If you have those products you can probably access http://diskstation.local/ or one of the others.

Comment: how to broadcast local hostnames to anyone on the same LAN?